# Androidx Guideline can't be cast to ViewGroup

Tags: java, android-studio, androidx, constraintlayout-guideline

I just migrate to androidx and I got and error like this

`androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline cannot be cast to android.view.ViewGroup`

It's working fine before I migrate my code to androidx.

I already check some solution about this casting problem, but mostly they have a small mistake like casting a layout inside the button.
And I already did some research and got a conclusion that this error showing because the androidx Guideline not a child of ViewGroup. But I can't find the solution yet for this one.

I include my xml and java code below

SettingAccActivity.java

```
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setContext(this);
    updateSharedPref(PreferenceConnector.ACTIVITY, this.getClass().getSimpleName());
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    FrameLayout contentFrameLayout = findViewById(R.id.frame_content);
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService( Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE );
    inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_settings_acc, contentFrameLayout);
... }
```

Note : error is on `inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_settings_acc, contentFrameLayout);`

activity_base.xml

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<include
    ... />

<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:id="@+id/layout_drawer"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:background="@color/light_gray"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/layout_bottom_navi"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/toolbar_main">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <ListView
        ... />

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>

<include
    ... />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

activity_setting_acc.xml

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/light_gray">

<include
    ... />

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/layout_row_password"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/padding_tiny"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/padding_normal"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/padding_normal"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/padding_normal"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/header_title">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guide_img_password"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.12" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img_remember_pass"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@id/guide_img_password"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@id/guide_img_password"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_remembermypasword_new" />

    ...

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

...

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Any suggestion / answer is a great help for me.

Thanks before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already find the solution.
When I adjust the layout from `android` to `androidx` there's a wrong update.
I change the old `ConstraintLayout` to `Guideline`